# Hint and User Input overlaying in a TextView

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio, kotlin

I've never seen this happen before, and have no idea what is causing it, my first choice was to hide hint with a piece of java code within the fragment, but I failed so hard at in that now I just wanna find a XML solution.
[image]

This is happening to every field, and I can't find anything wrong with the layout here, any insights?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText
            android:id="@+id/faq_contato_nome"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@string/hint_nome_contato"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:lines="1"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:textSize="15sp" />
    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText
            android:id="@+id/faq_contato_telefone"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@string/hint_telefone_contato"
            android:inputType="phone"
            android:lines="1"
            android:padding="10dip"
            android:textSize="15sp" />
    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText
            android:id="@+id/faq_contato_email"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@string/hint_email_contato"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
            android:lines="1"
            android:padding="10dip"
            android:textSize="15sp" />
    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText
            android:id="@+id/faq_contato_nome_empresa"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@string/hint_empresa_contato"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:lines="1"
            android:padding="10dip"
            android:textSize="15sp" />
    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText
            android:id="@+id/faq_contato_telefone_empresa"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@string/hint_tel_empresa_contato"
            android:inputType="phone"
            android:lines="1"
            android:padding="10dip"
            android:textSize="15sp" />
    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText
            android:id="@+id/faq_contato_matricula"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Digite sua matricula (Opcional)"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:lines="1"
            android:padding="10dip"
            android:textSize="15sp" />
    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

    <sinapse.com.br.estilo.component.CustonSpinner
        android:id="@+id/faq_contato_spinner_assunto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        app:hintText="@string/title_spinner" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/faq_contato_campo_mensagem"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="2dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="2dp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
        android:hint="@string/hint_areamensagem"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/faq_contato_numero_caracteres"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:text="@string/caracteres" />

    <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        android:id="@+id/faq_contato_btn_enviar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:text="@string/enviar" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/faq_contato_guideline"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_begin="13dp" />
</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: If you are using TextInputLayout, always provide hint in TextInputLayout only, not in the edittext.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with the following code may be it will help you.

```
//Remove padding from edittext
//Try to set hint on TextInputLayout instead of EditText
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="@string/hint_nome_contato">

 <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText
        android:id="@+id/faq_contato_nome"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:lines="1"
        android:textSize="15sp" />
    
</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is you setting a **padding** to your `EditText`, that's why the `EditText` components are not being given enough space to accommodate user's input without having to overlay with the hint. Simply get rid of paddings in your `EditText` components and it will run just fine. :)

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText
            android:id="@+id/faq_contato_telefone"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@string/hint_telefone_contato"
            android:inputType="phone"
            android:lines="1"
            android:textSize="15sp" />
    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

If you DO NOT want your hint to float. **(If you want your hint to completely disappear as soon as the user taps on the `EditText` box)**

You can add `app:hintEnabled="false"` in your `TextInputLayout`.
In this case, I think you can safely add your padding back on because the hint will disappear on user's tap.

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:hintEnabled="false">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText
            android:id="@+id/faq_contato_telefone"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@string/hint_telefone_contato"
            android:inputType="phone"
            android:lines="1"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:textSize="15sp" />
    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```